# Create Search Boxes to find Answers and Questions in Activity Tab

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, activity-tab

I would like to request you to add a new feature on StackOverflow.com that is related to **searching** an answer/question in the **Activity tab**.

This is because, there occurs some situations where we need to give answers based our previous answer/question.
That is, to take the help of already posted answer by us and extend that answer to the newly asked question.(**No duplicate questions**)

For this, we go to our **Activity -> Answers Tab** and do a manual search to fetch the previous answers.But, when the count of the answers is quite more (say 100 +) then it becomes a tedious job to find that already posted answer.
This scenario becomes same while finding already answered questions in **Activity -> Questions Tab**.

In order to solve this issue, I suggest you to create a search box (highlighted by red color) as in the below screenshots near answers and questions Tab that will fetch the relevant answer/question.

**Search Answer:**
[image: Search Answer]

**Search Question:**
[image: Search Question]

Many Thanks in Advance.

Comment: advanced search can do it: [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame+is%3Aanswer); [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame+is%3Aquestion)

Comment: advanced search will give questions & answers of all users, I suggest a feature in that we will be able to search our own questions/answers in activity tab. Using our previous experience we can answer quickly.

Comment: No, advanced search *can already search just your own posts* and in fact will do so *by default* in the search box if you're on your own profile. [tag:status-completed]

Comment: @NathanTuggy, can you please share the screenshot / location of advance search option?

Comment: @RohitGaikwad: Click in the search box on the right side of the topbar, which will be pre-populated with `user:6813506` or the like, and type in the additional search terms there.

Comment: @NathanTuggy, thanks it works fine. But I think It will be good if these search boxes are created near answer and questions tabs without pre-populated user id.

Comment: Personally I don't want more search boxes on the site. Just use the `user:me` filter in the normal search. Although I would support the search box dropping down with a UI to set up the search criteria, just like the Gmail interface does.